# Converting .net 1.1 to .net 2.0

Tags: .net

how we  can convert .net 1.1 to .net 2.0 without any change in code?

Comment: Why not just go the whole hog and jump to 4.0?

Answer (score 5):

I think there might be scenario where code changes are required and may be not. It all depend on your code base. For a start point you can check following links:

[.NET 1.1 to .NET 2.0 Migration](http://blogs.msdn.com/peterlau/archive/2006/05/11/595294.aspx)

[Migrating from .NET 1.1 to 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/swiss_dpe_team/archive/2008/04/10/migrating-from-net-1-1-to-2-0-3-0-and-3-5.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Not every program can be converted from 1.1 to 2.0 without any change to its code. You might get lucky on your project, though.

See the [breaking changes between 1.1 and 2.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2005/11/14/breaking-changes-between-net-framework-1-1-and-2-0.aspx).

Comment: That's just plain un-true. In general *you can*, and very easily. Of course, there are always cases where you get problems, but these are all resolvable.

Comment: @Dan: The question states "without any change in code". When I said "in general" I meant "there exists a program, where this is not possible". Damn mathematical education. =)

Comment: OK, understood - the new wording makes more sense to my English-educated mind :)

Answer (score 0):

I followed below steps and work for me

1. Change Target framework version 2.0 (I had 10 proj. in my solution)
2. Update Nuget packages with latest version (some of the previous packages are not compatible with .net core 2.0)
3. Build your solution, I got some error because some of the methods are obsolete.
   e.g 
   [image]
4. If you will get similar error you need to check suggested link and need to fix.

That's it. :)

You can explore .net 2.0 - https://youtu.be/Q2mMbjw6cLA